# Why does JSoup create empty files named after the link?

Tags: java, jsoup

Im trying to get the all the images of a website but why does Jsoup not only get the images of the page but also a create document named like the link after the slash?

```
        Elements imageElements = document.select("img[src$=.png], img[src$=.jpg], img[src$=.jpeg]");
    for(Element imageElement : imageElements){

        String strImageURL = imageElement.attr("abs:src");
```

[Here is the full code](https://github.com/krissemicolon/prnt.sc-image-fetcher/blob/master/src/Fetcher.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to fix it it is probably a prnt.sc issue:

Instead selecting the everything with the "img" tag like that:

```
Elements img = doc.getElementsByTag("img");
```

I selected everything with the file ending png, jpg and jpeg. Here the code:

```
Elements imageElements = document.select("img[src$=.png], img[src$=.jpg], img[src$=.jpeg]");
```